# Django repeating URLS

Tags: django, django-urls

New to Django. Setting up a wiki. When I need it proceed to the next page to add content it duplicates the URL, so we start here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mideastinfo/Start
```

and I have a lick saying "no content, would you like to create, and it is meant to go here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mideastinfo/Start/edit
```

instead it does this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mideastinfo/Start/mideastinfo/Start/edit
```

Which obviously doesn't exist.
Below is the urls.py

```
# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   (r'^mideastinfo/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'mideastinfo.wiki.views.edit_page'),
                   (r'^mideastinfo/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)+/save/$', 'mideastinfo.wiki.views.save_page'),
                   (r'^mideastinfo/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$', 'mideastinfo.wiki.views.view_page')
```

what am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help in advance, I'm a noob.

Here is the views.py:

```
# Create your views here.
from wiki.models import Page
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def view_page(request, page_name):
try:
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    return render_to_response("create.html", {"page_name":page_name}
) 
content = page.content
return render_to_response("view.html", {"page_name":page_name, "content":content})

def edit_page(request, page_name):
try:
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    content = page.content
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    content = ""
return render_to_response("edit.html", {"page_name":page_name, "content":content}
)

def save_page(request, page_name):
content = request.POST["content"]
try:
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    page.content = content
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    page = Page(name=pahe_name, conent=content)
page.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect("/mideastinfo/" + page_name + "/")
```

This is the template for the create page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{page_name}} = Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{page_name}}</h1>
    This page does not exist. <a href="/{{page_name}}/edit">Create?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and for the edit page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{page_name}} - Editing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Editing {{page_name}}</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/{{page_name}}/save/">
        <textarea name="content" rows="20" cols="60">{{content}}</textarea>         <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Page"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is just appending the path. Can you show the usage ? How is the url created ?

Comment: You probably need a leading slash before the urls in the templates.

Comment: I added the views.py that should show the usage, I believe. I still don't get why its appending it. I did try adding leading slashes in the template files, no dice. Thanks for looking.

Comment: The problem is not in the view. It should be in the view that calls the edit URL. One more recommendation, use `reverse`, instead of `("/mideastinfo/" + page_name + "/")`

Comment: Show your template @bamabacho

Comment: added templates. Thanks

Comment: did you forget the `mideastinfo` ?

Comment: tried it both ways, no difference. I was thinking it had to do with the fact that the way its structured, there is projects/mideastinfo/mideastinfo/my_app on the one hand and the templates sit in projects/mideastinfo/templates, could that be it? Though I did try moving it around and making the necessary changes, still to no avail.

Comment: when I type in manually everything works fine, just on the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `{url 'name' param %}` instead of hard code url in templates, and use `reverse('name')` to get corresponding url in views.py and other scripts:

**urls.py**

```
(r'^mideastinfo/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'mideastinfo.wiki.views.edit_page',name='edit'),
(r'^mideastinfo/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)+/save/$', 'mideastinfo.wiki.views.save_page',name = 'save'),
(r'^mideastinfo/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$', 'mideastinfo.wiki.views.view_page',name = 'view')
```

used in templates

```
{% url 'edit' 'page_name' %}
```

used in views.py or other scripts such as models.py

```
reverse('view', args=('value',))
```

In this way, you could fix your mistake, and some day if you want to modify your urls, just modify urls.py, that is all.

**UPDATED 2014 05 31**

in a high lever you can defined a `get_absolute_url()` in class(es) of your models.py.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Then you can redirect more easily.

`views.py` and so on

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def view2(request):
    obj = Model2.objects.get(id=33)
    return redirect(obj,permanent=True)
```

in templates use `{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}`

more see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

about redirect: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: For some reason I get a syntax error when I add name='edit' to the end of that line.

Comment: nevermind, fixed it! This seems like the right solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: OK, I updated my answer you could use `redirect(obj)`, things will more easily.